# Get previous and next row from current id

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I do to get the next row in a table?

```
`image_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment
`image_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL
`image_text` mediumtext NOT NULL
`image_date` datetime NOT NULL
`image_filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

If the current image is 3 for example and the next one is 7 etc. this won’t work:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = ".intval($_GET['id']));
echo $_GET['id']+1;
```

How should I do?

thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id < 3 ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 1 -- Previous
SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id > 3 ORDER BY image_id LIMIT 1 -- Next
```

Comment: very easy to understand and works well. tysm

Answer (score 7):

If you want to circle the records, you could use this:

```
-- previous or last, if there is no previous
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE image_id < 12345 OR image_id = MAX(image_id)
ORDER BY image_id DESC
LIMIT 1

-- next or first, if there is no next
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE image_id > 12345 OR image_id = MIN(image_id)
ORDER BY image_id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

---

The same with UNION, might be even more efficient:

```
-- previous or last, if there is no previous
(SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id < 12345 ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION (SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = (SELECT MAX(image_id) FROM images))
LIMIT 1

-- next or first, if there is no next
(SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id > 12345 ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION (SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = (SELECT MIN(image_id) FROM images))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your answer is really cool, and how about the case of table image has one more field:'image_type'. I want to select the next/first and previous/last which image_type=$img_type. Note that next/first or previous/last are for specific image_type($img_type), not for all image_type.

Comment: @AJOP Wrap the existing `WHERE` condition in parentheses and add your condition with `AND` to it.

Comment: I think I can't use MAX and MIN() function in Where clause, but I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images
                     WHERE image_id > ".intval($_GET['id'])." ORDER BY image_id LIMIT 1");

    <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>
```

Comment: Kids, please don't do this at home. This screams [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use PDO, and or parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please, for the love of the internet, don't built an SQL query yourself. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Please, for the love of StackOverflow, do not write this kind of answers. Use Comments.